# convert hexadecimal sting to byte array

Tags: python, hex, byte

I want to convert a hexadecimal string like `1030` to a byte array like `b'\x10\x30'`

I know we can use `bytearray.fromhex("1030")` or `"1030".decode("hex")`. However, I get output `'\x100'`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytearray(b'\x100')` is correct, you just interpret it wrong way. It is character `\x10` followed by character `0` (which happens to be ASCII for `\x30`).

Comment:  thanks a lot. I was just confused

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function in bytearray that does what you intend.

bytearray.fromhex("de ad be ef 00")

It returns a bytearray and it reads hex strings with or without space separator.